# Can your return Angular Components based on a parameter

Tags: angular, components

I’m wondering if the following is possible in angular.

I want to have several components that take the same base interface of properties, a string component, a date component, a integer component etc that all have different html, css, validation etc.

I then want to have a component called input that will be placed on a form and based off of the type of class given to it will render the correct component.

Is this at all possible without going down the route of having all the components in the base components wrapped in ngIf’s and without using dynamic declarations?

Comment: You can do it, just have a component as input-controls.component.html in that define all the input, select,textbox, checkbox, radio button whatever is required and from the parent component for example from home.component.html you can send the data to input-control.component.html using (input)='control name' and capture the input in input-control.component.html and have some *ngIf in input-control.component.html based on that show the controls and do the remaining logic

Comment: I already have this arrangement, I’d like to have a better way of doing it with the ngIfs if at all possible and be able to add additional controls without having to edit the base components layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dynamic loading component as described in this post: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/dynamically-loading-components-with-angular-cli-92a3c69bcd28.

In general you need to create a dynamic component that is using the "Comiler" object of angular core to create the component you want to create at a certain time.
By doing so you don't have to use that many *ngIf statements.

In this stackblitz I used that functionality to create dynamic fontawesome icons, you could use that functionality to create your own components: https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-module-with-fontawesome-z6zq2h